# Writing to SQL Server with SQLAlchemy is extremely slow

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am trying to insert a very small test csv file dataset (100 rows) to an existing table on a remote Microsoft SQL Server using Anaconda Python and SQLAlchemy on a Windows 10 machine. There are no errors so far but the upload is ridiculously slow. The job has been running for 2 days and is still not finished. So I assume there is something going very wrong in the background.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import datetime
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import event
import urllib

table = ...
timestamp = ...
schema = ...

table_short = table.split("_")[0]

# load csvs
all_csvs = glob.glob(...)
csv_list = []

for csv in all_csvs:
    df_csv = pd.read_csv(csv, index_col=None, header=None, delimiter=';')
    
    # add RecordSrc column
    df_csv.insert(0, "RecordSrc", csv.split("/")[-1], True)
    
    csv_list.append(df_csv)

df = pd.concat(csv_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

# load meta data
df_meta = pd.read_csv(...)

# adjust column names
column_names = []
column_names.append("RecordSrc")
column_names.extend(df_meta[3])
df.columns = column_names

# add LoadDate column
time = datetime.datetime.now()
df.insert(0, "LoadDate", time, True)

# add HashDiff column
df.insert(2, "HashDiff", 0, True)

# Establish connection to SQL Server
conn_str = (
    r'Driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;'
    r'Server=...;'
    r'Database=...;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)
quoted_conn_str = urllib.parse.quote_plus(conn_str)
engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted_conn_str), fast_executemany=True)
cnxn = engine.connect()

# check if table exists
table_exists = engine.dialect.has_table(engine, table, schema=schema)

# truncate table
query = "TRUNCATE TABLE [" + schema + "].[" + table + "]"
cnxn.execute(query)

@event.listns_for(engine, "before_cursor_execute")
def receive_before_cursor_execute(
       conn, cursor, statement, params, context, executemany
        ):
            if executemany:
                cursor.fast_executemany = True

# upload to SQL Server
df.to_sql(table, con=engine, schema=schema, index=False, if_exists='replace')

cnxn.close()

print("done")
```

I also tried setting the method='multi' parameter but this does not seem to make a difference. From what I read setting fast_executemany is one of the fastest options.

Edit: I was able to solve this issue after reading the comments. The problem is the truncate part that is blocking the rest of the process because it was not properly committed. I solved this by changing the execute line to:

```
cnxn.execution_options(autocommit=True).execute(query)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: That should take a second or two.  It's probably blocked by another session with an open transaction.

Comment: You could investigate the blocking queries using [sp_whoisactive](https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive/blob/master/who_is_active.sql)